# Theme isnt being applied on my React Component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Hi  ma facing a problem where i made the theme.js for the light and dark mode and for some reasons. The theme isnt being applied on. Below is my code for theme.js and App.js:

```
import { createContext, useState, useMemo } from "react";
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";

// color design tokens export
export const tokens = (mode) => ({
  ...(mode === "dark"
    ? {
        grey: {
          100: "#e0e0e0",
          200: "#c2c2c2",
          300: "#a3a3a3",
          400: "#858585",
          500: "#666666",
          600: "#525252",
          700: "#3d3d3d",
          800: "#292929",
          900: "#141414",
        },
        primary: {
          100: "#d0d1d5",
          200: "#a1a4ab",
          300: "#727681",
          400: "#1F2A40",
          500: "#141b2d",
          600: "#101624",
          700: "#0c101b",
          800: "#080b12",
          900: "#040509",
        },
        greenAccent: {
          100: "#dbf5ee",
          200: "#b7ebde",
          300: "#94e2cd",
          400: "#70d8bd",
          500: "#4cceac",
          600: "#3da58a",
          700: "#2e7c67",
          800: "#1e5245",
          900: "#0f2922",
        },
        redAccent: {
          100: "#f8dcdb",
          200: "#f1b9b7",
          300: "#e99592",
          400: "#e2726e",
          500: "#db4f4a",
          600: "#af3f3b",
          700: "#832f2c",
          800: "#58201e",
          900: "#2c100f",
        },
        blueAccent: {
          100: "#e1e2fe",
          200: "#c3c6fd",
          300: "#a4a9fc",
          400: "#868dfb",
          500: "#6870fa",
          600: "#535ac8",
          700: "#3e4396",
          800: "#2a2d64",
          900: "#151632",
        },
      }
    : {
        grey: {
          100: "#141414",
          200: "#292929",
          300: "#3d3d3d",
          400: "#525252",
          500: "#666666",
          600: "#858585",
          700: "#a3a3a3",
          800: "#c2c2c2",
          900: "#e0e0e0",
        },
        primary: {
          100: "#040509",
          200: "#080b12",
          300: "#0c101b",
          400: "#f2f0f0", // manually changed
          500: "#141b2d",
          600: "#1F2A40",
          700: "#727681",
          800: "#a1a4ab",
          900: "#d0d1d5",
        },
        greenAccent: {
          100: "#0f2922",
          200: "#1e5245",
          300: "#2e7c67",
          400: "#3da58a",
          500: "#4cceac",
          600: "#70d8bd",
          700: "#94e2cd",
          800: "#b7ebde",
          900: "#dbf5ee",
        },
        redAccent: {
          100: "#2c100f",
          200: "#58201e",
          300: "#832f2c",
          400: "#af3f3b",
          500: "#db4f4a",
          600: "#e2726e",
          700: "#e99592",
          800: "#f1b9b7",
          900: "#f8dcdb",
        },
        blueAccent: {
          100: "#151632",
          200: "#2a2d64",
          300: "#3e4396",
          400: "#535ac8",
          500: "#6870fa",
          600: "#868dfb",
          700: "#a4a9fc",
          800: "#c3c6fd",
          900: "#e1e2fe",
        },
      }),
});

// mui theme settings
export const themeSettings = (mode) => {
  const colors = tokens(mode);
  return {
    palette: {
      mode: mode,
      ...(mode === "dark"
        ? {
            // palette values for dark mode
            primary: {
              main: colors.primary[500],
            },
            secondary: {
              main: colors.greenAccent[500],
            },
            neutral: {
              dark: colors.grey[700],
              main: colors.grey[500],
              light: colors.grey[100],
            },
            background: {
              default: colors.primary[500],
            },
          }
        : {
            // palette values for light mode
            primary: {
              main: colors.primary[100],
            },
            secondary: {
              main: colors.greenAccent[500],
            },
            neutral: {
              dark: colors.grey[700],
              main: colors.grey[500],
              light: colors.grey[100],
            },
            background: {
              default: "#fcfcfc",
            },
          }),
    },
    typography: {
      fontFamily: ["Source Sans Pro", "sans-serif"].join(","),
      fontSize: 12,
      h1: {
        fontFamily: ["Source Sans Pro", "sans-serif"].join(","),
        fontSize: 40,
      },
      h2: {
        fontFamily: ["Source Sans Pro", "sans-serif"].join(","),
        fontSize: 32,
      },
      h3: {
        fontFamily: ["Source Sans Pro", "sans-serif"].join(","),
        fontSize: 24,
      },
      h4: {
        fontFamily: ["Source Sans Pro", "sans-serif"].join(","),
        fontSize: 20,
      },
      h5: {
        fontFamily: ["Source Sans Pro", "sans-serif"].join(","),
        fontSize: 16,
      },
      h6: {
        fontFamily: ["Source Sans Pro", "sans-serif"].join(","),
        fontSize: 14,
      },
    },
  };
};

// context for color mode
export const ColorModeContext = createContext({
  toggleColorMode: () => {},
});

export const useMode = () => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("dark");

  const colorMode = useMemo(
    () => ({
      toggleColorMode: () =>
        setMode((prev) => (prev === "light" ? "dark" : "light")),
    }),
    []
  );

  const theme = useMemo(() => createTheme(themeSettings(mode)), [mode]);
  return [theme, colorMode];
};
```

And for App.js:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Topbar from "./scenes/global/Topbar";
import Dashboard from "./scenes/dashboard";
import Team from "./scenes/team";
import Invoices from "./scenes/invoices";
import Contacts from "./scenes/contacts";
import Bar from "./scenes/bar";
import Form from "./scenes/form";
import Line from "./scenes/line";
import Pie from "./scenes/pie";
import FAQ from "./scenes/faq";
import Home from "./LandingPage";
import LoginPage from "./LoginPage";
import Geography from "./scenes/geography";
import { CssBaseline, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import { ColorModeContext, useMode } from "./theme";
import Calendar from "./scenes/calendar/calendar";
import SidebarComp from "./scenes/global/Sidebar";

function App() {
  const [theme, colorMode] = useMode();

  return (
    <ColorModeContext.Provider value={colorMode}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className="app">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="*" element={<NonDashboardLayout />} />
            <Route path="/dashboard/*" element={<DashboardLayout theme={theme} />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ColorModeContext.Provider>
  );
}


function NonDashboardLayout() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

function DashboardLayout({ theme }) {
  const [isSidebar, setIsSidebar] = useState(true);

  return (
    <>
      <ColorModeContext.Provider value={theme}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <SidebarComp isSidebar={isSidebar} />
          <main className="content">
            <Topbar setIsSidebar={setIsSidebar} />
            <Routes>
              <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
              <Route path="team" element={<Team />} />
              <Route path="contacts" element={<Contacts />} />
              <Route path="invoices" element={<Invoices />} />
              <Route path="form" element={<Form />} />
              <Route path="bar" element={<Bar />} />
              <Route path="pie" element={<Pie />} />
              <Route path="line" element={<Line />} />
              <Route path="faq" element={<FAQ />} />
              <Route path="calendar" element={<Calendar />} />
              <Route path="geography" element={<Geography />} />
            </Routes>
          </main>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </ColorModeContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}


export default App;
```

I have a toggle button in TopBar.js which is also mentioned below:

```
import { Box, IconButton, useTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { useContext } from "react";
import { ColorModeContext, tokens } from "../../theme";
import InputBase from "@mui/material/InputBase";
import LightModeOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/LightModeOutlined";
import DarkModeOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/DarkModeOutlined";
import NotificationsOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/NotificationsOutlined";
import SettingsOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/SettingsOutlined";
import PersonOutlinedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PersonOutlined";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";

const Topbar = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const colors = tokens(theme.palette.mode);
  const colorMode = useContext(ColorModeContext);

  return (
    <Box display="flex" justifyContent="space-between" p={2}>
      {/* SEARCH BAR */}
      <Box
        display="flex"
        backgroundColor={colors.primary[400]}
        borderRadius="3px"
      >
        <InputBase sx={{ ml: 2, flex: 1 }} placeholder="Search" />
        <IconButton type="button" sx={{ p: 1 }}>
          <SearchIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Box>

      {/* ICONS */}
      <Box display="flex">
        <IconButton onClick={colorMode.toggleColorMode}>
          {theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? (
            <DarkModeOutlinedIcon />
          ) : (
            <LightModeOutlinedIcon />
          )}
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton>
          <NotificationsOutlinedIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton>
          <SettingsOutlinedIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton>
          <PersonOutlinedIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default Topbar;
```

I didnt wanted my theme.js to be applied on the first 2 pages LandingPage.js and LoginForm.js. After fiding the way to found out I can apply the theme on selected pages. I chnaged my App.js. At first it had all the routes in one place. Now the code dont toggle between dark and white mode. Now it is also affecting my css pages where my one page went black while rest is being shown. Below is the image of what it looks like.[image: This is my landing page being affected by this dark theme]
and my sidebar looks like this:
[image: As you can my sidebar is looking white]
I tried checking in css but the only css that is white is for font text which i can show in comment. Iwill appreciate alot if someone can help me in this regard